# GoogleAuthUtil: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: android, oauth

I am using the Google Client API and the [GoogleAuthUtil.class](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil) to get access to the user's Google Drive Account.

```
String scope = "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE;
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getContext(), account.name, scope);
```

This is the whole magic. It worked the whole day but since a couple of hours I receive the following message when sending API calls:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
 {
   "code": 403,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "usageLimits",
       "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
       "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
       "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
     }
   ],
   "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```

I dont know how to use a API Key from the console instead of an oauth2 authentication.
There are two different "getToken()" messages. One has four parameters and the description for the last one says:

> extras: Bundle containing additional information that may be relevant to the
>   authentication scope.

But what do these information should look like? What informations do I have to put in the Bundle?

Comment: How about to sign up? Would be pretty easy, right?

Comment: I signed up and have all these API keys. But HOW should I put these Keys in the Bundle? bundle.putString("WHAT_KEY_RIGHT_HERE", API_KEY); ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dannnnnng. I received the whole time a valid token, but I never used it to perform the requests...
My solution:

```
GoogleCredential c = new GoogleCredential();
c.setAuthToken(myNewCoolToken);
```

Bad mistake...

Comment: Hey @Robert Hahn, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151