# Get request to export csv gives error "403 Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded."

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using drive + sheet api. Presently, I want to export the excel sheet in the csv format but while making get request I got the error in the console.

```
    function exportFirstCsv(excelId)
        {
            $.ajax({
              url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/" + excelId + '/export',
              type: "GET",
              data: { 
                mimeType: 'text/csv'                
              },
              success: function(response) {
                console.log('Now here');
                console.log(response);              
              },
              error: function(xhr) {
              }
            });
        }

got error :  {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
I want to export the file.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving error 403 in Google Drive API - Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042399/receiving-error-403-in-google-drive-api-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-ex)

Comment: I also tired the same request with the api key as query parameter but the problem is still same. How do i make an authorized call

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: All the steps of Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs  has done. I have the refresh token and I regeneration for access token has also completed. Can you please send me the proper url that we have to hit by get request that allow us to export the file in csv format

Comment: where in your code do you set the HTTP "Authorization" header?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included an http `Authorization` header, so your app is unauthorised. There is a daily limit for unauthorised apps which happens to be zero.

I suggest:-

1/ read about Google OAuth and how to authorise apps and make authenticated requests.

2/ learn to search for existing questions on StackOverflow. This question has been asked and answered many times, eg [Receiving error 403 in Google Drive API - Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042399/receiving-error-403-in-google-drive-api-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-ex?rq=1)