# python-social-auth can't use GoogleOAuth2

Tags: python, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I built the backend with `Django` framework for mobile client and I used `python-social-auth` for signing up users and it works for `Facebook` and `Twitter` but fails for `google-oauth2`, with the following error:

```
     {"detail":"{\n \"error\": {\n \"errors\": [\n {\n \"domain\": \"usageLimits\",
    \n \"reason\": \"dailyLimitExceededUnreg\",
\n \"message\": \"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.\",
\n \"extendedHelp\": \"https://code.google.com/apis/console\"\n }\n ],
\n \"code\": 403,
\n \"message\": \"Daily Limit for Unaut henticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.\"\n }\n}\n"}
```

I debugged google backend source code in social package and I found it failed on `return` statement:

```
 return self.get_json(url, params={ 'access_token': access_token, 'alt': 'json' })
```

I don't know why it fails, Any help in fixing this issue is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GoogleAuthUtil: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078588/googleauthutil-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded)

Comment: @Armfoot Yes i have the same error with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078588/googleauthutil-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded but it's about java or maybe android usage with google-oauth and in my case i use python with python social package so his 
solution doesn't fit my case

Comment: Angel, from the [answer in that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13078826/1326147), the google-oauth works based on a GoogleCredential, I believe your problem is similar: your access_token is invalid or it wasn't properly used. The code you are using to define it would be useful to address your problem..

Comment: @Armfoot finally it's bad access_token. i use this link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground  for get my google+ access token and it works like a charm

Comment: Great! You can add an answer explaining that and mark it as accepted, you will get reputation and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thank all for your help.
That finally I found issue was due to the use of bad access token. i use this link http://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and i choose google+ in google api list and after generate key i exchanged it with access token for get my google+ access token and it works like a charm when i run curl commande on my python view url.
if someone have the same issue and need more help it can ask me i will explain more...